# How to print an array without brackets but with the quotation marks on it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

How to print an array without brackets but with the quotation marks on it?

I have:

```
a = ['1','2','3','4','5']
' '.join(map(str, a))
```

Result I'm receiving:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Expected Result (wanted):

```
'1','2','3','4','5'
```

(with the commas and the quotation marks)

Comment: But it doesn't even give your result though? It gives `'1 2 3 4 5'`

Comment: `print(', '.join(repr(i) for i in a))` will do proper quoting even with quotation marks in the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because when you do `' '.join(...)`, you're getting one big string instead of a list of them. If you want to keep the quotes, you'll need to add them back in yourself:

```
>>> print(', '.join("'{}'".format(x) for x in a))
'1', '2', '3', '4', '5'
```

Comment: thanks god you answered my question! It was perfect!

Comment: but  I need the commas as well

Comment: Updated. Adding commas back just takes adding a comma to `join`.

Answer (score 5):

Do this:

```
a = ['1','2','3','4','5']
print(str(a).strip('[]'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['1','2','3','4','5'] 
print([str(item) for item in a])
```

I like it like this.

Comment: That's not what he wants. It's still a list, just items are `str`, but his intended output is str, not list.

Answer (score 0):

```
", ".join("'{}'".format(x) for x in a)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is always good to provide some context to your answer. Thanks

Comment: @LonelyNeuron Thanks for the advice, it will be better next time :)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to catch up the train with old school string building solution

```
a = ['1','2','3','4','5']
out_string=''
for i in a:
    out_string+="'"+ i +"'"+', '
print(out_string.rstrip(', ')) # '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'
```